# Implicit Flow is not reacting properly in Azure AD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, implicit-flow

I have a React SPA that calls a Node API that in turns calls another Node API. I configured the first API to allow for user1 to have access. I configured the second API to ONLY allow the first API to access it. When user1 clicks the button to make the call to the api, using the code below, I get this error:

> AADSTS700051: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application.

Code:

```
forecastButtonState = async () => { 
authContext.then(async data => {
  const pData = {latitude: "38.8106", longitude:"-90.6998"};

  const url = "http://localhost:3005/api/getforecast";

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(pData),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  };

  const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
    adalFetch(data, data.config.endpoints.api, fetch, url, options);
  
  try {
    const { response } = await adalApiFetch(axios, url, options);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);        
  }      
}); 
};
```

The "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" is set to true in the manifest and that seems to be the solution for everything I have found so far. Also, under Authentication and Implicit grant both Access tokens and ID tokens are checked

I am baffled as to what is the problem. I have it configured the way it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [on-behalf-of-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) for the issue. It serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

The steps that follow constitute the OBO(on-behalf-of) flow and are explained with the help of the following diagram.

[image]

---

> About the Error: AADSTS700051: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application.

You could modify the app manifest(Navigate to App registrations -> your application -> Manifest
) or select token in the Authentication (Navigate to App registrations -> your application -> Authentication).

**Manifest:**

[image]

**Authentication:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Try this URL, make sure the api can be called well.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={your-client-id}
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Comment: I will try the OBO. I already had the settings that you show in the your last screenshots. That is why I couldn't understand why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Obie_One Try the url(in the update message). I have already tried the error, and I can only reproduce it when the Access tokens and ID tokens are unchecked.